# How to prove that given operators form an algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, lie-algebra

I am new to Group theory and representations and I'm having trouble with this problem in an exercise:

> Given the two oscillator algebra $$[a, a^†] = 1$$ $$[b, b^†] = 1$$
>   $$[a, b] = 0$$ show that the forgoing generators satisfy $SU(1,1)$
>   algebra. $$[K_+, K_−] = 2K_z$$ $$[a, K_+] = a^†b^†$$ $$[a, K_−] = ab$$

I've read that $SU(1,1)$ algebra is defined by the the commutations:
 $[K_1, K_2] = −iK_0$ , $ [K_0, K_1] = iK_2$ ,
 $[K_2, K_0] = iK_1$ .

I assumed that it was just a matter of plugging in the given generators and obtaining these relations to show that they satisfy the given algebra but I'm unable to do this.

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me with some tips on commutator manipulation and the general strategy one would use in solving such problems.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.